What is the reason why flxible function in SPM-based restplus in matlab does not work
enter image description here
enter image description here
The pipeline function in restplus, the spm-based preprocessing software in matlab, cannot be used. When flexibe is selected, the file source cannot be input and the file cannot be selected during preprocessing.
How to solve this problem?
